# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() What is the solution to this problem? The problem is in Postion

Tags: java, android, adapter

What is the solution to this problem? The problem is in Position
here code is here :

1. List item

   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderOrderShop holder, int position) {

   ```
   ModelOrderShop modelOrderShop = orderShopArrayList.get(position);

   String orderId = modelOrderShop.getOrderId();
   String orderBy = modelOrderShop.getOrderBy();
   String orderCost = modelOrderShop.getOrderCost();
   String orderStatus = modelOrderShop.getOrderStatus();
   String orderTime = modelOrderShop.getOrderTime();
   String orderTo = modelOrderShop.getOrderTo();

   //load user /buyer Info
    loadUserInfo(modelOrderShop,holder);
   //set data
   holder.amountTv.setText("Amount : شيكل"+orderCost);
   holder.statusTv.setText(orderStatus);
   holder.orderIdTv.setText("Order ID :"+orderId);
   if (orderStatus.equals("In Progress")){
       holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
   }else  if (orderStatus.equals("Completed")){
       holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
   }else  if (orderStatus.equals("Canceled")){
       holder.statusTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
   }
   ```

   //convert Time
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(orderTime));
   String formatedDate = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy",calendar).toString();
   holder.orderDateTv.setText(formatedDate);

   ```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           //open order details
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, OrderDetailsSellerActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("orderId",orderId);//to load order info
           intent.putExtra("orderBy",orderBy);//to load user info
           context.startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of code

```
ModelOrderShop modelOrderShop = orderShopArrayList.get(position);
```

And Do it like this

```
orderShopArrayList.get(position).getOrderId();
```

and do it for all the below strings.

Comment: loadUserInfo(modelOrderShop,holder);
It shows an error